# How can I write an R dataframe to hive using an ODBC connection?

Tags: r, hive

Using the RODBC package, I can manually write a HiveQL statement that will create a table for me, but is there a way to leverage the sqlSave() function to write an entire table to Hive for me?

```
myconn <- odbcConnect(dsn = "dsn1",uid="username1",pwd="password1")
test <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,5), b = c("one", "two", "three", "four", 
"five"))

sqlSave(myconn, dat = test, tablename = "schema1.test")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in sqlSave(myconn, dat = test, tablename = "cao_analytics.test") : 
HY000 80 [Hortonworks][Hardy] (80) Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown 
in server while executing query. Error message from server: Error while 
compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:34 cannot recognize input 
near '"rownames"' 'varchar' '(' in column specification
[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'CREATE TABLE cao_analytics.test  
("rownames" varchar(255), "a" DOUBLE, "b" varchar(255))'
```